# Ubuntu 20.04 Nvidia 440 login freeze

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, 20.04

So, I'm getting some weird behavior on Ubuntu 20.04 with a GTX 1080 (If hardware matters). When using the 440 drivers installed with the "Additional Drivers" built in GUI utility, upon restart my computer hangs after I enter my login password.  (All of them cause the hang, but currently on 440)

The screen flashes away with passcode success, never blackens, but then the plain purple login quickly comes back and is stuck there forever, mouse and all response to everything frozen - even disconnecting monitors gets nearly no response). If I remove the Nvidia drivers this issue disappears with them (But I need them for some other libraries...).

I did however discover a weird, unusual fix that's consistent for me and lets me keep the drivers - So I thought I'd share in the hopes of getting a real solution, but at worst help provide a workaround.

If I load into my boot device select screen from the mobo (Not the one where I can select recovery mode for ubuntu) and select the Ubuntu uefi drive instead of it starting up to Ubuntu automatically, the loading proceeds normally but after the purple login screen appears, it flashes black and refreshes but I login perfectly normally. If I allow ubuntu to load itself just from power on, the full freeze awaits me after I provide the right password.

I did try some of the answers [here first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229933/login-freeze-after-update-to-20-04), but it didn't fix the problem (And honestly, should the built in, guided install GUI lead to a brick? I couldn't even swap to a text terminal on the login screen, same freeze there with purple screen staying there frozen)

Comment: Addendum: This did not work for me the next day. However, setting it to suspend then resuming does now work...?