# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after login

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

After I updated my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 i cannot manage to successfully log in. The screen freezes on a desktop view with no response on input from the mouse or keyboard. I've tried everything from the question below, with no success.

[Login freeze after update to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229933/login-freeze-after-update-to-20-04)

I'm only able to log into Ubuntu Wayland.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?