# Ubuntu hangs after login following upgrade 18.04 -> 20.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

After upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, ubuntu now hangs following the login screen.  In a fresh reboot, I get to the login screen just fine.  After I enter my password, the screen transitions to a black screen with my machine's hardware logo (HP Omen) and stays like that forever.

There's a ton of "ubuntu hangs after login" posts out there, all of which seem to suggest different solutions.  I've tried this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/aazyhi/ubuntu_freezes_after_login/
which had no effect that I could see.

What should I try next?  What information can I post to make the problem easier to diagnose?  Many thanks for the holiday help.

---

Update: I am able to log into the machine using chrome remote desktop.  When I'm logged into the physical machine and then log in using CRD, if I open a terminal on CRD it appears on the primary machine's physical monitor rather than the virtual desktop that requested the terminal.  The mouse on the physical monitor is the default "X" from xwindows.

I have the default "Ubuntu" WM and Cinnamon installed.  In what I'm describing above both the CRD machine and the physical machine are running "Ubuntu".  Cinnamon gives a login loop (successful login returns to the login page).

Comment: what is the RAM memory value of your system?

Comment: @baponkar Here's the RAM on my machine:
    $ free -g
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:             15           1           8           0           5          13
    Swap:             0           0           0

Comment: Also tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229933/login-freeze-after-update-to-20-04.  From what I can see (output from apt-get install) I have the latest nvidia drivers.  Not sure what else the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

There was some combination of updating nvidia drivers, removing the word '`splash`' from `/etc/default/grub`, and

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-remote-desktop
```

Things started working after the last.