# After 20.04 upgrade my system freezes after log in unless I use Wayland

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, wayland, cursor

I was running Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS. I've just upgraded 20.04.

When it boots and gets to the new log in screen, my arrow cursor is frozen and the trackpad does nothing and so the only thing I can do is reboot.

I managed to fix this by going into the boot menu and **enabling** secure boot. I'm not sure why this would work, but the cursor now moves.

I am now able to type my password and log in to the system, however: when I do so, the cursor is again stuck on the bottom right of the desktop and won't move UNLESS I choose to log in to Ubuntu Wayland and then everything seems okay.

Can someone explain what is happening?

I believe that I have had this problem before when I first got my machine and I was told various things, but it always seemed to involve some combination of (i) turning off / on secure book and (ii) removing / adding nvidia driver.

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229933/login-freeze-after-update-to-20-04) which clearly had the same problem, but there isn't a clear solution in the answers and I don't want to start experimenting and making the problem worse.

Comment: First, I would reboot to secure mode, add network, update system, use tasksel, remove all Desktops and add desired ones again. Then, if problem still exists, I would read log files like dmesg or syslog to find out whats going on

Comment: Try [this solution from you quoted AU thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253842/332437) first. If it doesn't work, try a newer NVIDIA driver. The ones from 20.04 are quite dated now.

Comment: I have tried to follow the answers in that solution. I have updated my nvidia drivers to nvidia-driver-470. Didn't fix the issue. I also tried the solution regarding `nvidia_drm.modeset=1`. I tried both methods. Still no joy.

Comment: @qba-dev I'm not sure what you mean by "add network" sorry.

Comment: @user1551817 after getting to secure boot you need to activate networking to be able to update system or use Tasksel

Comment: @qba-dev **"secure-boot"** is not the correct term. **Grub Recovery Mode** is the correct term to use in this case. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-secure-boot) is what secure boot means. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) is what recovery mode means.

Comment: @someone thanks for clarification. So, we can say it is a Recovery Mode

Comment: @user1551817 networking is turned off by default in Recovery (99% sure). Check [this](https://www.osradar.com/enable-network-ubuntu-recovery-mode/)

Comment: @qba-dev okay, but I'm in Wayland (which I'm using now). So that has wifi etc. Or do I really have to go into recovery mode?

Comment: @user1551817 no, I don't think you need Recovery, but in my opinion it is best way to install/uninstall Desktops, using tasksel

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the output of `apt list --installed | grep gdm3` followed by `cat /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Comment: Before you login with X11, login on a tty (for eg Ctrl+Shift+F3) and run something like `journalctl -xef -p warning` to analyze what's going on while login in to X.. Copy the relevant output to your post.