# How do I boot to recovery mode in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, secure-boot

To solve [another problem I am having](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1381082/after-20-04-upgrade-my-system-freezes-after-log-in-unless-i-use-wayland), it has been suggested that I need to "reboot to secure (actually recovery) mode". I don't know exactly what this means.

I have been in the BIOS of my Dell XPS laptop and I have ensured that *Enable Secure Boot* is switched on. Does that mean that I am already securely booting?

Comment: It sounds to me as if they meant you to boot into *recovery* mode. That would allow you to do all the stuff in the first comment. I am not advocating the solution given there, just trying to interpret it.

Comment: **The user in their comment means ["boot to recovery mode"](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/1460940).**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To boot into recovery mode, follow the steps [in Takkat's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/1460940), which I also mention here.

1. Before the [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) (boot splash) screen appears, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (could be another key, as it depends on the laptop's manufacturer) to enter the **GRUB boot menu**.
2. After you're in the GRUB menu, select `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.

   [image: Grub menu]
3. In the advanced options, select a **recovery kernel**.

   [image: Advanced Options for Ubuntu]
4. Wait till you get to the **Recovery Menu**:

   [image: Rescue options]

In the Recovery Menu you'll find a few **recovery options** for your system.

- `resume` - Boot normally to your main OS.
- `clean` - This option cleans your OS and removes obsoleted and unnecessary packages.
- `dpkg` - Try to fix package manager issues.
- `failsafeX` - Start the system in Safe graphics mode.
- `fsck` - Check errors in the file system. This option won't work in recent Ubuntu systems as the disk is mounted.
- `grub` - Updates the GRUB boot loader (`sudo update-grub`).
- `network` - Enable Wi-Fi and network services.
- `root` - It will drop you to a root prompt to execute commands as the `root` user.
- `system-summary` - Shows information about your system.

Comment: Just in case - with `Esc` is enough - it working through `VirtualBox`