# After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10, when screen turns off, it does not come back on

Tags: drivers, kernel, screen, 21.10, amdgpu

I upgraded my Ubuntu laptop to the 21.10 and now when my screen turns off such as when it is on standby, it does not turn on again. More specifically, it turns on (the pixels make light) but it stay black.  On my secondary screen, all works great.

My Linux kernel version is `5.13.0-28-generic`. I tried to downgrade the kernel and that resolved the screen issue, but some other functionality like internet no longer worked.

I looked into re-installing the driver, but I didn't manage to do it.

Here is the result of the `lspci` command:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev da)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues with kernel 5.13.0-28. Pick an older kernel when booting up your machine (in Grub, select Advanced options and pick kernel 5.13.0-27).

Some sources:

- https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amd-driver-broken-on-ubuntu-again/m-p/510972#M152642
- [Monitor issues after kernel update 5.13.0-28](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390561/monitor-issues-after-kernel-update-5-13-0-28)

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  Please take the [tour]. Though I am not disputing the validity of your claim that kernel 5.13.0-28 has numerous issues, it would be good to see at least a legitimate supporting hyperlink in your answer.

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, you are right, I was too quick to post without relevant sources - I wanted to help the requester as fast as possible. References added now.

Comment: Please also take the [tour].