# Issue with sleep mode: device gets stuck and needs restart (will not wake)

Tags: networking, shutdown, services, 21.10

When I activate sleep mode, my laptop gets stuck and hangs. I have to switch it off and it takes a long time to open with the power switch.

I'm using kubuntu 21.10 my kernel ver:-5.13.0-28-generic

```
Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.22.5
```

System msi modern amd
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz

Comment: Provide more information about your hardware

Comment: I did not find a </> here so i post it in crypt pad inxi output. https://cryptpad.fr/code/#/2/code/view/QF0oDmhgzAysQLrrtr7PwkY3nTXEJ33rneaqUpjVki4/

Comment: You should [edit] your question and enter any requested information right into your original text and not give links to some obscure web sites!

Comment: Doing that will make my question a mess with.i have provided inxi output in a opensource most secure project called cryptpad so it is easy to see the code and i am provideing some info like cpu and something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here. General instability with this kernel update. Experiencing freezes while in use + just like you sometimes it just hangs on suspend and I have to hard reset the laptop... I ended up using the version 5.13.0-27 and no more problems ! In Grub, select Advanced options and pick kernel 5.13.0-27

Potential related report : [After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10, when screen turns off, it does not come back on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390660/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-10-when-screen-turns-off-it-does-not-come-back-on/1391199#1391199)

Comment: Yes you r right, it also worked for me. Do anyone report the bug as i have not found anything in the bugzilla,if reported please share the link @mbousq

Comment: Hi, I don't know  how to report bugs ... @limanux

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org look into it posta bug in kernel and ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

it's normal, when your laptop is in hibernating mode, it saves sessions on ram or on the hard drive

here are the two main causes:

```
1- you don't have much ram
2- you have an HDD
```

*-By NacreousDawn596, answering questions just for fun.*

Comment: No wrong 1 is i have good amount of ram unused like more than 5-6gb of it free. And swap 3gb created which is unused so no lack of ram and i have a very good fast nvme m.2 ssd and it is actually pretty fast so no hdd here.

Comment: Can i get some feedback to solve my issue else i ahve to reflash