# Help fix booting error: "Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO], AE_NOT_FOUND" after dual boot (with windows) installing ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, brightness, battery

As mentioned in the title, I recently installed ubuntu 22.04.01 in my Lenovo Legion 5 (bios version: H1CN47WW) laptop dual booting with windows 10. From the start there has been an error message while booting accompanied by some issues. Namely, the brightness can't be changed and the battery drains really fast (only on ubuntu, windows is still fine).

The error is:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO], AE_NOT_FOUND
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PID log size 0 is invalid
pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PID log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 228012/6083568 files, 3864795/24472945 blocks
```

I have tried looking up the same error online, but I can't find the same one. I have already tried adding the following line of code in the grub file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

I also tried updating grub and the operating system, but nothing works.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? That "AE_NOT_FOUND error" is not the problem. I think we all have it, for whatever reason. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-ssd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530

Comment: I tried updating the UEFI & SSD firmware. It did not work.

Comment: So are you able to get to grub menu? And boot recovery mode, or remove quiet splash to see where boot stops?

Comment: Yes, I get the grub menu each time I reboot. Booting in recovery mode does not do anything special. I also tried using fsck in recovery mode as well, but no errors were found.

Comment: If you get grub menu, then you are booting . Most often it is because of nVidia video driver not correctly installed. When you installed did you use Safe Boot and choose to install the restricted drivers. That would install the correct nVidia driver. If at recovery mode, you enable Internet and then in terminal run 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` Did you also do all the other updates in recovery mode? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384994/how-do-i-boot-to-recovery-mode-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Apparently, booting in recovery mode changed something. The screen brightness slider suddenly works despite the boot error still being there. I already have the correct nvidea drivers installed. In fact I had to downgrade to resolve another system error. But you are right that the error is there, because when I run this command I get an error. Anyways, the main problem was the brightness control, since that is fixed I thank you very much!

Comment: When you changed nvidia driver, did you purge old one first. That is required with drivers to avoid conflicts. New driver does not correctly replace old. # Houseclean out all old versions to avoid issues
sudo apt-get remove --purge < nvidiadriverpackagename>

Comment: I uninstalled the incorrect (old) nvidea drivers, got a demonic yellow screen, then re-installed the appropriate drivers in recovery mode. You were right about about there being unecessary drivers, but that was not the issue causing the boot error, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: No, nothing I tried worked, though another issue I was having was fixed in the proccess (brightness control).